# Get Value from JSON or XML (WHOIS API) Python

Tags: python, json, xml, whois

I need to take only one value from an XML/JSON file I read into a value.
https://whoisapi.whoisxmlapi.com/whois/google.com?format=XML

here is my code example :

```
import json
try:
from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
from urllib2 import urlopen
domainName = 'google.com';
apiKey = 'YourApiKey'
url = 'https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?'\
+ 'domainName=' + domainName + '&apiKey=' + apiKey + "&outputFormat=JSON"
testing=urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
test = json.loads(whoisdb)
registrar = test['WhoisRecord']['registrarName']
domain['whois-created']   = test['WhoisRecord']['createdDate']
```

And if I am using the value "registrar" later, I get a "Keyerror".

Unfortunaly neither of the other Questions helped me...

Edit : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBjW.png ,well he gets the value in the variable, but I still get this error.(I printed the error while running)

Comment: Try listing all the keys in the WhoIsRecord section with `print(test["WhoisRecord"].keys())` and see if `registrarName` is there. It might just be spelled differently.

Comment: registrarName is spelled right. I use the dnstwist code from github.

Comment: Have you tried listing the keys?

Comment: print `test` and share it here.

Comment: See here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481108/whois-command-not-returning-useful-information. You better do `registrar = test['WhoisRecord'].get('registrarName')` so you will get None and not an exception

Comment: @tituszban yeah thanks, but "registrarName" was right.